How to Connect New Tyvek Homewrap to Existing HomeWrap after Leak Repair
Hoping to get some advice with a repair.
In the picture attached, the upstairs window was leaking.  It has been removed, as well as the stucco/stone around and below the window - as water has damaged the OSB below the leak.  The house has Tyvek HomeWrap with a stucco paper overtop before adding the stucco/stone layer.  The window removal and subsequent waterproofing is completely understood and not a problem.
My question is how does one properly adhere new Tyvek Homewrap to existing homewrap at/under the stone/stucco where the transition occurs - where the underlying wood does not need to be replaced and the stones are not removed?  The process of removing the stones is already difficult and it seems unlikely that the HomeWrap underneath will not get damaged. How is the moisture barrier maintained at the transition line between existing Homewrap (possibly with damage due to stone removal) and new Homewrap in repaired area?  I'm sure we can use some tyvek seam tape or Zip tape to connect the old and new but is that the best method to ensure an effective moisture barrier?
Thanks in advance.


So the window seems well in place, not "removed". Details / images of what you are working with would help.

Added another picture for you with stone removed.  The window has already been sealed and set back in place.  My question is more on the transition between new to old HomeWrap.  The new picture is the best I have - ignore the black Henry paper as that was just temporary until we figure out the transition. You can see the flap of new HomeWrap at the top.

That's a tough situation which I've faced several times. It's a matter of attempting to get lap for flow wherever you possibly can, and taping or caulking where you can't.
If there's any gap at all behind the stucco or stone, maybe consider sliding some aluminum coil stock flashing in over the lower house wrap. Then you can fasten the top edge of that and lap/tape the new house wrap onto the flashing.
Sometimes the only way to get complete confidence in a repair is to open it up all the way down. Otherwise, do your best and hope for the best as a result.

I think the ability to slide anything under the stone/stucco is very limited due to the cladding staples holding the stone to the OSB.

Does it make sense to overlap new HomeWrap over existing HomeWrap before the last stone in the column, Zip Tape over the seam and then liquid flash over that as far to/under the un-removed stone as possible?

I'm not familiar with two out of three of those products. Read their labels.

I would apply the new tyvek to the existing renovated area and bridge the two wraps with the aluminum flashing to go between the staples, but applying a caulk on the backside of the aluminum and sliding in and pressing in place to bridge/seal the gap . I would then use expanding foam around the clips to seal where your aluminum does not cover the gaps.

I would underlap new Tyvek and tape in place with Tyvek tape.  On the top the underlap distance is probably not that critical beyond a couple inches, but on the sides I'd get as much as practical.

@Huesmann Underlap new Tyvek over old or old over new? Or does it not really matter?

It matters. Anything intended to shed water needs proper lap, taped or not.

@Huesmann I get the vertical lapping - starting at the bottom and working upward so top layers are always over bottom layers.  I didn't think it was as big a deal with the horizontal. So, to confirm, you're saying correct method for horizontal lap is new Tyvek UNDER old Tyvek?

@Alex that's the easiest way to to it.  Hard to lap the sides "new on the outside" without some odd cuts.

You're welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers.
